# How can I prove that something is an open cover?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

I want to prove that the union of some intervals forms an open cover for some segment. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It depends on the intervals. As your question stands now that you have edited out all the specifics, it is impossible to say anything concrete.  In general it might be very difficult, if the family of intervals if very complicated.  About all the can be said of your question in its present form is that the proof should follow this pattern: Let $x$ be some point of the segment; then show that there is some interval $I$ in the family of intervals that contains $x$.

Answer (score 4):

If $x \in (0,1)$ then $0<x<1$. By the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$, we can conclude that that there exist natural numbers $m,n$ such that $1/m < x < 1-1/n$. In particular we can take $k=\max \{ m,n \}$ to get $1/k < x < 1-1/k$. I think you can conclude your result from here.